# BT Chat проверка доступности

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Делаю простой BT чат. Часть кода взята из сэмпла гугла. Так вот вопрос, можем ли мы в поиске девайсов для подключения отоброжать только те на которых установлен или доступен клиент нашего БТ чата (возможно запущен наш БТ сокет)?
[Cэмпл гугла](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно. Поиск устройств разбит на 2 фазы:

1. Device discovery - поиск устройств (хоть каких нибудь). Bluetooth устройство обязано иметь `DiscoveryAgent` - агент поиска устройств. Результатом поиска будет массив `RemoteDevice`. Пример [например тут](http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-device-discovery/)
2. Далее можно организовать поиск сервисов в массиве `RemoteDevice`. За это отвечает метод `DiscoveryAgent.searchServices()`. Только надо не забыть, что на удаленном устройства необходимо прописать какие сервисы он "выставляет" наружу. Это делается через публикацию в т.н. SDDB - Service Discovery Database (вся процедура описана [здесь](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetoothintro/))

Comment: Осталось сюда прикрутить 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/DeviceListActivity.html
Нужно выводить только те которые имеют сервис этой же программы

Comment: Ну прикручивайте - кто девелопер? Я или вы?

Comment: (вся процедура описана здесь)
Ссылка не рабочая)

Comment: Как бы хотелось бы попробывать, а ссылка досихпор ссылается на хешкод

Comment: исправил ссылку